# How to Prove $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ = i?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What would be a formal way to prove the above statement?

Comment: What's your definition of $i$?

Comment: Also, what's your definition of $z^{\frac12}$?

Comment: @Botond $i^2$ = -1

Comment: You can just square both sides of the equality, although it's not a proof because $\left( (-1)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right)^2$ is also equal to $(-i)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
(-1)^{1/2}
&=e^{\ln{(-1)}/2}\\
&=e^{i\pi/2}\\
&=\cos{(\pi/2)}+i\sin{(\pi/2)}\\
&=i\\
\end{align}$$
Assuming the principal valued complex natural logarithm.